# String split on specific characters

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string like;

```
'[abc] [def] [zzz]'
```

How would I be able to split it into three parts:

```
abc
def
zzz
```

Comment: Remove the brackets from the string, and then perform an ordinary split on the spaces.

Comment: Ah, but what if the next string is `'[abc def] [zzz]'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> findall('\[([^\]]*)\]', '[abc] [def] [zzz]')
['abc', 'def', 'zzz']
>>>
```

All of the Regex syntax used above is explained in the link, but here is a quick breakdown:

```
\[      # [
(       # The start of a capture group
[^\]]*  # Zero or more characters that are not ]
)       # The end of the capture group
\]      # ]
```

---

For those who want a non-Regex solution, you could always use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> [x[1:-1] for x in '[abc] [def] [zzz]'.split()]
['abc', 'def', 'zzz']
>>>
```

`[1:-1]` strips off the square brackets on each end of `x`.

Comment: Using `[^\]]*` instead of `.*?` is significantly faster (I can see a 3x improvement with longer groups and strings) (the list-comprehension seems fastest anyway...)

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
s = '[abc] [def] [zzz]'
s = [i.strip('[]') for i in s.split()]
```

Comment: why do you need to specify `' '` in split?